# Why minutes not get selected in jquery datetime picker

Tags: datetimepicker

I am using jquery ui datetime picker and I am unable to select minute drop down value for first hour.

I have set `stepMinute` to 5 and `minDateTime` to 0.

If `minute dropdown` contain 2,7,12,17 etc. instead of 0,5,10,15 then we can not get selected minute value in minute dropdown. It is showing selected value as empty.

Below is my javascript code:

```
$(function() { 
var d1 = new Date();
var n1 = d1.getHours(); 
  $('#pick_date').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
    timeFormat: "   HH:mm",
    controlType: 'select',
    stepMinute: 5,
    minDateTime:0,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {    

              }
  });
});
```